# For Loop that counts up and down from a start index inside range

Tags: c#, for-loop, math, iteration, pseudocode

I'm having trouble developing a for-loop that starts at a given integer (*start*) and then counts up **and** down from this starting point inside a given range (*min* to *max*). I want the result to be in order by distance to the given start. If a for-loop is not the right tool here, i am open for other suggestions!

Since this is hard to explain i have a example down below:

```
var start = 4;
var max = 10;
var min = 0;
var stepSize = 1;
for(var i=startIndex; i>=min && i<=max; ???) {
  Console.WriteLine(i)
}
```

The result should look like this:

```
4 5 3 6 2 7 1 8 0 9 10
```

The really tricky part for me is the end where the alternation has to stop in order to reach the max value of 10 and not go below 0 in the meantime.

I started experimenting and had a solution that would work for the first bit:

```
const int start = 4;
const int stepSize = 1;
    
for (var (i,j,k) = (start,1,5); Math.Abs(j)<=11; k=(k+j),j=-j-Math.Sign(j)*stepSize,i=(k+(start-5))%11) {
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

This works fine for the first part where alternation is needed, but it breaks once the alternation needs to stop. The result from this experiment is:

```
4 5 3 6 2 7 1 8 0 9 -1
```

Comment: Are you allowed to call `WriteLine` more than once in the loop body?

Comment: `WriteLine` is only a placeholder for a function, but yes.

Comment: No fancy approach, but [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VTK55A) also works

Comment: @AstridE. - right. || and then check again inside to really get all the values. Better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is with a `for` loop, but like others have already alluded to, I think other structures are better suited for your task:

```
  public static void Main() {
    int start = 4;
    int max = 10;
    int min = 0;
    int stepSize = 1;
    for(int i=start, j=start; i>=min || j<=max; i-=stepSize, j+=stepSize) {
      if (i==start) {
        Console.Write(i + " ");
      }
      else {
        if (j <= max) {
          Console.Write(j + " ");
        }
        if (i >= min) {
          Console.Write(i + " ");    
        }        
      }      
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The sequence you are after:

```
4 5 3 6 2 7 1 8 0 9 10
```

Could be specified as the following:

```
4 - 3 - 2 - 1 - 0
- 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 10 
- - - - - - - - - - --
4 5 3 6 2 7 1 8 0 9 10
```

Which using something like [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ), could be expressed like this:

```cs
Sequence(4, 0).Interleave(Sequence(5, 10))
```

Obviously, you control the `start`, `max` and `min` by controlling the values of both sequences. So, say you want to start from 7, going up and down towards 1 as the minimum value, and 14 as the maximum. The call would be like:

```cs
Sequence(7, 1).Interleave(Sequence(8, 14))
```

Lastly, this also allows you to easily change from a "up-down" to a "down-up" by swapping the intervals. Using the example above:

```cs
Sequence(8, 14).Interleave(Sequence(7, 1))
```

Note that `Sequence` also has an overload that takes a `step` argument, so you can additionally expand the examples below with arbitrary step increments and not only 1.

Answer (score 2):

Since you explicitly stated that you want a for loop that produces the pattern, how about this approach:

Find the larger "distance" first and let the loop run until this point, not starting with 0. In the loop check in both directions and do the calculations inline and call the method once beforehand with the original value.

```
int x = 4;
int min = 0;
int max = 10;

int largest = Math.Max(Math.Abs(min - x), Math.Abs(max - x));

YourMethod(x);
for (int i = 1; i <= largest; i++)
{
    if (x + i <= max)
        YourMethod(x + i);
    if (x - i >= min)
        YourMethod(x - i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple but elegant solution could generate the number sequence you want like so:

```
static IEnumerable<int>
UpDownCount(int start, int lower, int upper)
{
    int i = start, j = start;
    yield return start;
    while (true)
    {
        bool ilimit = ++i <= upper,
            jlimit = --j >= lower;
        if (ilimit)
            yield return i;
        if (jlimit)
            yield return j;
        if (!(ilimit || jlimit))
            yield break;
    }
}
```

Then you can use that sequence with LINQ or a simple `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (int i in UpDownCount(4, 0, 10))
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: Would be perfect, if it also included a custom `stepSize` (instead of just ++ or --).

Comment: Of course one could make this and other improvements.